# How to adjust two ImageViews one above the other

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm trying to add two images, one above the other, the thing is that with my `LinearLayout` is creating a blank space that doesn't adjust those `ImageView`. What's the problem on my `activity2.xml`?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

### Edit

The problem is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw6TJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use [`adjustViewBounds`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds)

Add this line in your `ImageView`

`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Comment: He also has to change the width fill to wrap.